# How to make the side mirrors open or close with the locks of the car?

Tags: toyota, corolla, locks, mirrors

I have a corolla 2012 and I want to make some modifications on it. I want the side mirrors to close and open when I press the the lock and unlock button of the remote control.

Anyone has any idea of that?

Comment: If it doesn't come as a standard feature (even just getting them to close), you'd have to retrofit mirrors or the mechanism to make it happen into your current mirrors. Going to be some hefty grafting.

Comment: The already have motors and open/close by pressing a single push button. Dose that make it easier?

Comment: Absolutely makes it easier, but I don't really have an answer for you. Would assume you'd have to reprogram the body control module (BCM - if that's what Toyota uses) to control the mirrors. So, this is an exercise in programming, not installation.

Comment: Actually, a relay wired with the control side wired to the door lock actuator, and then the work contacts duplicating the mirror pushbutton wiring might work and require no programming.  Yet I was unaware of any Corolla having those kinds of mirrors.  I'm also not certain they would work without KeyOn.  @Selfsuf - can you roll down the driver's window, lock the car, and press the mirror button to see if they fold?

Comment: Alas, somebody beat me to the punch.  Is this what you want? https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=svjqeGU6UPw

Comment: That's mighty cool, but have you really thought out the reliability of your proposal?  It wouldn't surprise me if those motors quit working after 1000 cycles.  You are increasing the cycles on those motors way beyond original design assumptions.

Comment: If the fold-in mirrors weren't designed to be used each time the car is parked, why else would they exist? I seriously doubt reliability is a concern here.

Comment: @lathejockey81 the mirrors are designed with motors so that they can be fold to drive in narrow place or street. Also, you can fold them whenever you park your car.

Answer (score 2):

This is the perfect use case for the [Pac tr-7](http://www.pac-audio.com/PACProductData/TR7/1_Instructions/tr-7_instructions_010505.pdf). It's basically a programmable relay. You can set it up to do all sorts of tasks, usually around bypassing the requirement that a vehicle be in park for video to play or disabling traction control on startup. Good luck man.

Comment: Great answer and welcome to the site! Could you provide more detail on how/where specifically OP could utilize this device in his Corolla? Thanks for contributing!.